# Type inference on abstract class from inheriting concrete class

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract, type-inference

What I'm trying to do here is infer the type T of the abstract class from the type of the concrete inheriting class.

For example, I have a generic abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyAbstract<T> where T : class {
    //Methods...
}
```

And an inheriting concrete class which inherits `MyAbstract`:

```
public class MyConcrete : MyAbstract<MyConcrete> { 
    //Methods..
}
```

Now, I this works just fine, but I find it verbose for this abstract class, as it will always be of the type of the inheriting class.  I know that it's possible to do generic type inference for methods (thank you Jon Skeet http://joelabrahamsson.com/a-neat-little-type-inference-trick-with-c/), but I can't seem to figure out a way to do it for the above.

Ideally, I'd have

```
//Type T on MyAbstract is inferred to be MyConcrete.
public class MyConcrete : MyAbstract {
    //Methods...
}
```

Is what I want possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @JacquesB My abstract class contains common logic for instantiating `ILogger`s.  Part of creating the Logger is naming the logger according to the class that the logger is logging for.  Therefore, I use `typeof(T).Name` to get the name of the inheriting class when creating the logger.

Comment: Do you need to use inheritance for this? If you just create the logger in a method, you can provide `this` as an argument.

Comment: @JacquesB So glad i posted here!  Great idea, that definitely solves my problem, it was one of those OF COUUUURSE moments for me.  Thanks again :)

Comment: @JacquesB Can you tell me if I'm on the right track?  When passing `this` to the base class method, I'm using `dynamic` as the data type.  Then going to use reflection to get the name/type of the caller.  Does that sound right to you? Or is the need for reflection a bit of a code smell for something relatively simple?  At this point I could see just passing in the `Type` of the caller to the base class.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `dynamic` or reflection for this. You define the method as something like `GetLogger<T>(T subclass) ` and call it as `GetLogger(this)` from the subclass.

Comment: Ah, so that's how to do property type inference.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was resolved in the comments. For those looking, this is not possible.

However, I only needed the type information of the sub-class in the base class, and so I ended up implementing type inference in the base class methods.

My code ended up looking like this

```
public abstract class MyAbstract {
    DoSomething<T>(T caller){
        //foo
    }
}
```

And in the concrete:

```
public class MyConcrete : MyAbstract {
    base.DoSomething(this);
}
```

Shout out to JacquesB for helping me.